# Powershell Exporting to CSV adding data to new column

Tags: powershell

I am trying to import list of names from a text document and  would like the data to go into the next available column of a csv file each time I run the script without overwriting the previous column.

I am also new to powershell.

```
# Define the path to the CSV file
$csvFilePath = "C:\Temp\ReadData.txt"

# Load the CSV file
$csvData = Import-Csv $csvFilePath

# Determine the next available column index
$nextColumnIndex = $csvData[0].PSObject.Properties.Count

# Define the data you want to add to the new column
$newColumnData = "csvData"  # Replace with your data source

# Add the new data to each row
foreach ($row in $csvData) {
    $Date = Get-Date -format ("MM/dd/yyyy")
    $newColumnName = "$Date"
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $newColumnName -Value $csvData
}

# Save the updated CSV data to a new file
$csvData | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\IPTest.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there.

This  `$newColumnName = "$Date"`  injects the *value* of the $Date variable into the string.  You just want the string "Date".

And this

```
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $newColumnName -Value $csvData
```

should be

```
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $newColumnName -Value $Date
```

so

```
foreach ($row in $csvData) 
{
    $Date = Get-Date -format ("MM/dd/yyyy")
    $newColumnName = "Date"
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty  -Name $newColumnName -Value $Date
}
```